# does openjdk/openjfx fully support WebView (WebSockets)?

Tags: webview, websocket, java-8, java

I consider if it's possible to replace Oracle JDK with OpenJDK to build and run my application. It uses Java 8 WebSocket communination. Does OpenJDK / OpenJFX VM fully support WebSockets as Oracle JVM does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSocket support is Java EE feature while OpenJDK is a Java SE implementation. Support of Java EE features depends not on your JDK but on your Java EE implementation (e.g. Glassfish). Every licensed Java EE implemetation (app server) must have WebSocket support since it is part of Java EE.